# Expanding blended strokes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke, workflow, blending

My question is different than [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128210/illustrator-expanding-blended-strokes).

I have created a design with blended lines:

[image]

And now I would like each of the intermediate steps between the two base strokes to become a stroke as well.

**"Flatten transparency"** doesn't work, because it only converts some lines, and it converts them to outlines so I have two strokes around each line instead of one:

[image]

"Expand" [is not an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvfdn.jpg) (because CS6?).

And **"Expand Appearance"** doesn't work either, because it does this:

[image]

Since I am creating a **Blend** between two **Strokes**, I would very much like the result to be two **Strokes**. Seems logical that there'd be a way to do this.

**How can I turn Blended Strokes into actual Strokes?**

Comment: I don't get the same result as you when I use *Object > Expand* on a similar design.  It works as expected. [See example here](https://imgur.com/nhgcAVJ) I'm not sure what you did. Maybe check your initial strokes are basic strokes without any profile.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for sharing this! I am selecting "Expand appearance", "Expand" is greyed out/unusable so not an option for some reason.

Comment: not on my copy. Expand is available after creating a simple step blend of two strokes.  Maybe check you have basic strokes and not some kind of stroke profile applied.

Comment: @BillyKerr How do I check that? I simply created with the paintbrush tool

Comment: I think that's the source of your problem .  The paint brush doesn't make basic strokes. It strokes paths with a brush.  Use the Pen Tool or Pencil Tool to make basic strokes instead.  You can see the "basic" setting in the options along the top in the GIF I shared. If a path has a brush applied, you can change it to "basic" there too.

Comment: If it's not clear enough, have a look at [this screen capture](https://imgur.com/UNcqu4h)

Comment: @BillyKerr When I select the expanded paths, the information you get on the curves [is not to be found on my screen](https://imgur.com/a/RXfnrcU), even in the Stroke panel (notice how the top of the window looks so different).

Comment: You need to select one path, not the blend. You need to make sure the strokes are basic before you make the blend. My copy is AI CC, but as far as I know this was also available in CS6.  I don't have an old copy to check however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113434/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-micromachine).

Comment: Can't use chat [because I use a VPN, I'm assuming the IP is banned](https://imgur.com/a/FWYgflM). One can only chose the "Basic" definition after the stroke is created, and before creating the blend. [Not before creating the stroke](https://imgur.com/a/6ZktNdF). Not after creating the blend, [the Definition option is gone](https://imgur.com/a/8kzAo13). But when someone has created a Blend with a different brush definition (as if we needed restrictions on that...) the Expand option that works is the duplicate one from the Blend menu (see accepted answer). Thanks!

Comment: You can go into the blend in isolation mode and select each of the paths individually and change it to Basic, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @BillyKerr sounds like you could make this an additional answer then! Thanks a lot for the follow up!

Comment: OK, I've  added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it almost right, but need to stick to the options under the `Blend` menu:

- Make your blend and select it.
- To turn the blend into separate strokes go to `Object → Blend → Expand`.
- This will actually create a group of strokes, which you can then ungroup and edit each piece individually, if needed.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Very weird UI decisions on their behalf, but that's nothing new lol.

Comment: *Object > Expand* works for this too. [See example here](https://imgur.com/nhgcAVJ)

Comment: See my other comment or the edited question, "Expand is not an option".

Answer (score 1):

Further to some exchange in the comments, the real reason for the problem was discovered.

The reason Expand was greyed out for you is because you used the Brush Tool to make the paths, which applied a brush to the path. It wasn't a basic stroke. This means you when you tried to do Expand the Blend, only Expand Appearance was available, and this expanded the brush strokes too which messed everything up.

Ideally, you should have initially created your paths with the Pen Tool or Pencil Tool instead of the Brush Tool. This would have ensured the paths only had a Basic stroke, i.e. no Brush applied. Then when you applied the Blend, Expand wouldn't have been greyed out.

Since you already applied the Blend on brushed paths, to fix it you can enter the Blend in isolation mode, select each path, and change them to Basic in the Control bar along the top. Exit isolation mode, and now Expand will no longer be greyed out.

Comment: Thank you! A totally valid answer, which might require more time (the part about selecting the path in isolation mode), but works well!

Comment: @MicroMachine You can just double click the blend to enter it in isolation mode, then select each path and change to Basic, and then double click outside in a blank area to exit isolation mode. It's not really that complicated.